# CKEditor: Editing templates (e.g. PHP, JSP, ASP, ... i.e. non-standard HTML) 

Tags: php, javascript, ckeditor

Hi all once again ! I'm developing [this plugin to edit *PHP* pages](http://www.youtube.com/user/greatsoftw#p/c/ABED7BA09947CA55) using *CKEditor* (please watch demo videos for further details **;o)**. Everything works fine if I try to insert *PHP* code inside `<pre>` tag so as to render the code inside that page.

The fact is that I need to insert *PHP* code directly inside the code of target web page (well it's a *PHP* page indeed ...) because the idea is to insert *PHP* snippets that will be evaluated and expanded later in server-side.

In [this demo video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8lW8griL0BE) you can see that once I insert *PHP* code directly inside `<div>` tag (i.e. in source mode) and switch back to source mode again then the whole *PHP* block is sanitized thus replaced by `&nbsp;` entity. The same happens if the plugin tries to insert the same snippet (i.e. in *WYSIWYG* mode) once *Ok* button is pressed.

So questions are :

1. Is it possible to do something so as to instruct *CKEditor* to not obfuscate 
   *PHP* block ?
2. Does anybody has a hint or a way to work around this behavior ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Use the [config.protectedSource](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.protectedSource) setting, the page even list how you can use it with PHP

Comment: Hi ! I tried this and it works when switching back and forth between *WYSIWYG* and source code. So thanks , I made some progress. However when using the dialog and trying to insert *PHP* code inside `div` element (i.e. node) using `CKEDITOR.dom.element.setHtml()` it still obfuscates *PHP* snippet and inserts `&nbsp;` entity instead. Should I use another function ? Which one ?

Comment: First of all, your problem is just that when no special processing is applied, the browser is the one that misunderstands the PHP tags, so you need to protect that kind of content in order to save and read it. If you want to create such editor, then you'll have to work directly with the protected content, both in order to read it when you want to edit it, and to encode it again when you want to save it back. So the first step would be to load some PHP code in source mode and then look at how it's available in design mode, then when you want to save it you just have to follow the reverse steps.

Comment: Thnx for the pointers. I finally managed to get this done, you may see this demo ( http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OhKIofzLAp0 ), BTW. The only side-effect is that copy & paste operations are no longer supported.